# Xcode download: "The certificate for this server is invalid"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Is anyone other then me getting this error trying to download the docs in Xcode 6?

> Could not download and install iOS 8.1. The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “devimages.apple.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this problem on my Mac

Comment: It happened before? https://twitter.com/passy/status/471216874680631296 said "Apple forget to renew the TLS cert"

Comment: I got the same problem as well..

Comment: I'll pile on here. +1. I especially love the choices you get.

Comment: Me too, I received this, this morning

Comment: Seems temporary as all of us on here are still within the same day... This happened to me 5 minutes ago

Comment: Yep, definitely embarrassing for Apple!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Keychain Access to change the trust for the cert from Use System Default to Always Trust. For me it was the cert a248.e.akamai.net. After downloading the docs I switched it back to Use System Defaults. Or you can wait for Apple to correct the mistake.

Comment: Open `https://devimages.apple.com` in Safari. When you get the warning, expand the certificate and choose Always Trust. Close Safari and Xcode will now install the documentation.

Comment: Or search for the cert name in Keychain Access, which is what I did. Either should get you there.

Comment: @cristis your comment should be the accepted answer

Comment: @Asqan, I am not able to view "Always Trust" button. This answer was long back, Currently I am seeing only error and no action to do anything further.

Comment: @JiteshW see the answer of "kakashy". You have to open the section "Trust" in order to see it. Normally, if you go to that website "with https protocol" you get the warning and there you have the option "show certificate" or such a thing that leads to the dialog kakashy uploaded.

Comment: @Asqan Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved this problem adding the certificate to my keychain, you can download from [this site](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net) and configure the trust option in `Always Trust`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the workaround. Seems like Apple has forgotten to renew this certificate.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I got exactly the same problem, try investigate using google chrome browser.
It's turn out that the provided certificate! is not match URL itself.

[image]

Could be apple web administrator mess.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @M.Deinum but it's the reason of the warning isn't it?

Comment: Technically, it does answer the question. The question was "Is anyone other than me getting this error..." :)